# Using the result of a CTE to query from table without cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, common-table-expression

I need to query from a table which is a result of a `CTE` query e.g.

```
;WITH CTE
AS
( 
  SELECT TableName
    FROM dbo.TableContainingListOfTableNames        
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

This will return me the names of the tables which I need to query data from.

[image: Names of tables returned from table store]

Can I use the `CTE` to query from the respective tables e.g. `SELECT * FROM dbo.[1006UN]`?  I know I could use a temp table to store these values and use a cursor to iterate with dynamic sql but I do not want to use a cursor, if at all possible.

I have tried something as simple as:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.[CTE]
```

Which gives me the error:

> Invalid object name 'dbo.CTE'.

And have went further to attempt to use dynamic SQL with the CTE:

```
DECLARE @query1 VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @query1 = N';WITH CTE
AS
(
  SELECT TableName  
    FROM dbo.TableContainingListOfTableNames    
)
SELECT * FROM dbo.["' + CTE + '"] '

EXECUTE(@query1)
```

Which gives me the error:

> Invalid column name 'CTE'.

So firstly, is it possible to achieve this? And if not, are there any alternatives which can achieve this (avoiding cursors)?

Comment: A cte will not be within the `dbo` schema. It is constructed temporary within your batch and is only available there. Thus addressing it via `dbo.[CTE]` will not work because such an object does not exist.

Comment: Just try `SELECT * FROM CTE` - since a CTE is only an "inline, in-memory" objects, it's not stored into any schema ....

Comment: Are your table names actually `dbo.[TableName]` you're mixing up the result from the cte with the dynamic sql to read from your table.

Comment: @marc_s @Jamiec Yes I know `SELECT * FROM CTE` will work and get me a list of `TableName`s, however I need to actually query from the returned `TableName`s, I have updated the question with the result of selecting from the CTE with returned `TableName`s

Comment: @Adwaenyth do you know of any alternative ways to approach this?

Comment: @Sandman If you want the data to persist after the CTE, dump it in a temporary table. `WITH CTE AS () INSERT INTO @Temp () SELECT *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can be done. It's irrelevant if you use CTE or not. Once you have your tables names you can create and concatenate dynamic SELECT statements.

```
DECLARE @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = '';

WITH CTE AS
( 
  SELECT TableName
  FROM dbo.TableContainingListOfTableNames        
)
SELECT @query = @query + 'SELECT * FROM ' + QUOTENAME(TableName) + '; '
FROM CTE;

PRINT @query; --run print first to check
EXEC (@query);
```